# sample map reduce script in python for hive produces exception

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I am learning hive. I have setup a table named `records`. With schema as follows:

```
year        : string
temperature : int
quality     : int
```

Here are sample rows

```
1999 28 3
2000 28 3
2001 30 2
```

Now I wrote a sample map reduce script in python exactly as specified in the book Hadoop The Definitive Guide:

```
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    (year,tmp,q) = line.strip().split()
    if (tmp != '9999' and re.match("[01459]",q)):
        print "%s\t%s" % (year,tmp)
```

I run this using following command:

```
ADD FILE /usr/local/hadoop/programs/sample_mapreduce.py;
SELECT TRANSFORM(year, temperature, quality)
USING 'sample_mapreduce.py'
AS year,temperature;
```

Execution fails. On the terminal I get this:

```
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2012-08-23 18:30:28,506 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2012-08-23 18:30:59,647 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201208231754_0005 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_201208231754_0005_m_000002 (and more) from job job_201208231754_0005
Exception in thread "Thread-103" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while reading from task log url
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.errors.TaskLogProcessor.getErrors(TaskLogProcessor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JobDebugger.showJobFailDebugInfo(JobDebugger.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JobDebugger.run(JobDebugger.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://master:50060/tasklog?taskid=attempt_201208231754_0005_m_000000_2&start=-8193
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.errors.TaskLogProcessor.getErrors(TaskLogProcessor.java:120)
    ... 3 more
```

I go to failed job list and this is the stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hit error while closing ..
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ScriptOperator.close(ScriptOperator.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:193)
    ... 8 more
```

The same trace repeated 3 times more.

Please, can someone help me with this? What is wrong here? I am going exactly by the book. What seems to be the problem. There are two errors it seems. On terminal it says that it can't read from task log url. In the failed job list, the exception says something different. Please help

Comment: I don't have any experience with hadoop/hive so I won't hazard a guess at an answer but doing a quick experiment where I ran your python script standalone and typed your sample data rows into stdin at the CLI was successful - from a strictly python perspective the code works as expected.

Comment: yeah, that python script is correct. Has to be, it's from a very famous hadoop reference book :D.

Comment: Thank you for posting this question. I was looking for a similar example. Very handy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to stedrr log from the hadoop admin interface and saw that there was syntax error from python. Then I found that when I created hive table the field delimiter was tab. And in the `split()` i hadn't mentioned. So I changed it to `split('\t')` and it worked alright !

Comment: I'm trying to query a table someone else created. I think I may be having the same problem you describe. Do you know how to check what delimiter was used when the table was created?

Answer (score 0):

just use 'describe formatted ' and near the bottom of the output you'll find 'Storage Desc Params:' which describe any delimiters used.